# How should I do select statement between one column with another one that related?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that look like this:

[image: table1]

The result that I need is which empid that their passportno has been changed by user='12345'. 
empid is employee ID and userid is HR Personnel.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM audit_is_emppersonal
WHERE date between '09/25/2017' and 
'12/12/2017' 
 and userid='12345'
```

**update

This is my expected result:
[image]

As u can see, it only appear empid that passportno has been changed by userid='12345'

Comment: Not getting your question by this information.

Comment: Please show the expected result in order to clarify what you want.

Comment: Thank you. Next time show your sample data as pasted text please instead of images, though.

Comment: Alright Thorsten. Thanks a lot. Actually I can't access stackoverflow using my office network so I have to post question using my phone. Anyway, I used your solution and it works! Thanks again! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate on the employee under the conditions you described, and then check for employees having more than one passport number.  This would imply that user `12345` in fact changed the passport number for that employee.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT empid
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE
        date BETWEEN '09/25/2017' AND '12/12/2017' AND
        userid = '12345'
    GROUP BY empid
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT passportno) > 1 AND
           SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'AFTER UPD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
)

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    empid IN (SELECT empid FROM cte);
```

Comment: This query also works for me however it only appear empid. Actually I want to view all information but I can't select * from this query

Comment: @bennybenito I placed my inital query into a CTE.  You may select all records from your table on condition of the `empid` being returned by this CTE.

Comment: It works but not returns the passportno that has changed. It returns empid who has more than one row  of passportno  in the table. I did some changed in my post in case u don't understand

Comment: @bennybenito I updated again to check that the duplicated passport occurs with an after update record.

Comment: Actually I just understand your query. I forget to mention that there are condition where userid =12345 did not update passportno for empid. Your query also return the changes on another column, such as marital status. So, your query is right but it just not returns empid that their passportno has changed by that user. Anyway, I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: Then your table has a problem.  How do we detect the case where both the marital status and passport changed?

Comment: Hmm. Now you mention and I just think about it because I'm not the one who create the table. But currently I just want to pull out empid that changed in passportno column.

Comment: I think my latest query is already doing this.  It returns all `empid` records where a) passport has changed and b) the action reports an update

Comment: Okay Tim. Many thanks. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your requirement you can use ROW_NUMBER:

```
WITH Latest_Passport_Update AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid, action ORDER BY date DESC) AS Latest
    FROM audit_is_emppersonal
    WHERE date between '09/25/2017' and '12/12/2017'
)
SELECT * FROM Latest_Passport_Update
WHERE Latest = 1
    AND userid = '12345'
```

Comment: This query did returns the data which has been modified. However, it only appear Before UPD(before update) data. If I want to view both,which is before and after update passportno which one should I change? Sorry I'm still newbie with sql

Comment: @bennybenito isn't it that date between range in your WHERE clause? I kept it as it is. Try removing the date check

Comment: @bennybenito okay just add 'action' to the PARTITION BY clause. Updated the query above

Comment: Thanks a lot Tony. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are showing it seems you always have two records for one `date`, one with action `'BEFORE UPD'`, one with action `'AFTER UPD'` and you want to see when `passwordno` was changed in such a process.

```
select
  bu.userid,
  bu.date,
  bu.empid,
  bu.passportno as passportno_before_update,
  au.passportno as passportno_after_update
from (select * from audit_is_emppersonal where action = 'BEFORE UPD') bu
join (select * from audit_is_emppersonal where action = 'AFTER UPD') au
  on  au.userid     =  bu.userid 
  and au.empid      =  bu.empid
  and au.date       =  bu.date 
  and au.passportno <> bu.passportno
where bu.userid = 12345
  and bu.date between '20170925' and '20171212';
```

(You may have to adjust the `ON` clause slightly according to what must match exactly to identify two records for the same update.)

Comment: Hi Thorsten. Thanks for your solution. But I'm getting error  converting data type nvarchar to numeric. Still trying to fix that.

Comment: If `userid` is `nvarchar` and can hold non-numeric values (which would be quite rare for an ID), then change `where bu.userid = 12345` to `where bu.userid = '12345'`.

Comment: Okay Thorsten, I will try it. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEAD` and `LAG` to look into the following and preceding record:

```
select empid, passportno, marital_status, action, userid, date
from
(
  select
    empid, passportno, marital_status, action, userid, date,
    lag(date)        over (order by date, empid, userid) as prev_date,
    lag(empid)       over (order by date, empid, userid) as prev_empid,
    lag(userid)      over (order by date, empid, userid) as prev_userid,
    lag(passportno)  over (order by date, empid, userid) as prev_passportno,
    lead(date)       over (order by date, empid, userid) as next_date,
    lead(empid)      over (order by date, empid, userid) as next_empid,
    lead(userid)     over (order by date, empid, userid) as next_userid,
    lead(passportno) over (order by date, empid, userid) as next_passportno
  from audit_is_emppersonal
  where userid = '12345'
    and date between '20170925' and '20171212'
) data
where
(
  date       =  prev_date        and 
  empid      =  prev_empid       and
  userid     =  prev_userid      and
  passportno <> prev_passportno
)
or
(
  date       =  next_date        and 
  empid      =  next_empid       and
  userid     =  next_userid      and
  passportno <> next_passportno
)
order by date, empid, userid, action desc;
```

(Again, you may have to adjust comparision. Is the `date` always exactly the same in two records of the same update for instance? If not, you'd have to change `date = prev_date` and `date = next_date` accordingly.)